# indexing a "has many" property in Grails

Tags: grails, indexing, grails-orm, has-many

Is it possible to have an index on a hasMany property?

```
Class Author(){

 static hasMany = [books: Book]

  static mapping = {
    books index:'book_id'
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
Class Author(){

 static hasMany = [books: Book]
  List books // Generates column `book_idx` in table for Book.

static mapping = {
      books indexColumn: [name: "book", type: Integer]
    }
}
```